# Remove vertical space between two text elements <p> and <h1>

Tags: html, css, text

Cant seem to find how to remove vertical space between two text elements, There are some similar problems on this website but doesn't seem to actually work.

HTML Code:

```
<p>this website is</p> <h1>Encrypted</h1>
```

it seems that I would have to use a position code, but when I use a position code that lets other elements get close to it, the text gets pushed to another spot on the website

Comment: Just set the `margin` CSS appropriately.  `0` if you want.

Comment: No matter how much I change the margins, The space between the two elements are always the same

Comment: Not sure how to help you then without knowing more context.  You'd have to show us your actual code and what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, changed the wrong margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove white space between elements using CSS:

Horizontal being (top and bottom space)

```
h1, p {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
line-height: /* adjust to tweak wierd fonts */;
}
```

Vertical being (left and right space)

```
.parent {
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
}

h1, p {
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j4638zfm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Every browser has pre-set styles for elements. `p` and header tags have margins set. You can change this by using `margin: 0;`: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fwz7v9r/)

You may also benefit from using a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) to avoid these issues.

Also, I don't imagine a scenario where the word "encrypted" in your code should be using an `<h1>` tag: [How to properly use h1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405282/how-to-properly-use-h1-in-html5)

Comment: Thank you, not sure why so many disliked the post, I guess this website isn't very noob friendly

Comment: Its difficult to answer questions fully without more context. Typically you will want to include your CSS (or anything you have attempted) as well. And everyone loves a jsfiddle.net of the issue too.